# How to shift array elements in RPG?

Tags: arrays, ibm-midrange

I am aware of the fact that A loop can be used to move each element to its new destination, but is there any simpler and more elegant solution for the problem? Clearly MOVEA doesn't help here too much, as it does not work on the same array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift down using the [`SUBARR`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzasd/sc092508880.htm) function.

```
 /FREE
    %subarr(array:1) = %subarr(array:2); // Shift elements
    array(%elem(array)) = *blanks;       // Reset the remaining element
 /END-FREE
```

---

```
C                   EVAL      %SUBARR(array:1) = %SUBARR(array:2)
C                   EVAL      array(%ELEM(array)) = *BLANKS
```

Shifting up requires the use of a temporary array or storage due to overlap.

Comment: Is this a fully free style implementation?

Comment: @God_of_Thunder It can be free form or fixed.

Comment: Nifty. I believe this function was introduced in V5R3, so those on an older AS/400 will not be able to use this. (My company only just recently moved from V5R2 to V5R4.)

Comment: Do you know that we can rely on elements being assigned "left to right"? The manual (which you linked to) states that "if the source part of the array *overlaps* the target part of the array, unpredictable results can occur" (emphasis mine). To me, that implies that if for whatever reason, the compiler believes that it's more efficient to assign elements right to left (or inside out or what have you), that it is free to do so. Even if it always assigns left to right *now*, maybe some future version of the compiler will choose otherwise.

Comment: James - As John points out, isn't a down-shift (as you are using it here) going to overlap as well?  See, this is why I've tried to get into completely functional coding...

Answer (score 0):

The [**memmove() — Copy Bytes**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rtref/memmove.htm) C Library function can safely copy overlapping memory areas left-to-right or right-to-left. One use for me is after scanning a string for an embedded apostrophe. If I find one, I take the string starting at that position and move (i.e., 'copy') the bytes one position to the right. This results in a doubled embedded apostrophe with all following bytes shifted one position.

The function also returns a pointer for the new position, and I use that (plus 1) as the starting point to scan the remainder of the string for the next embedded apostrophe. I loop until the scan returns no hits. A string is essentially just an 'array' of bytes, so it works just as well with actual arrays.